# Traverse Multi-Level JSON Object in Java Google Maps

Tags: java, android, json, api

I'm current calling the [link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Irvine,CA&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA&sensor=false) in my Android project.

How can I traverse the array that looks like this to get duration.text?

I currently have the base Json object and am trying to use `getJSONObject` and`getJSONArray` but not having any luck.

```
{"routes" : 
[
 {"legs" : [{"duration" : {"text" : "52 mins","value" : 3106 },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this snippet it will find the "text" from the legs array

```
            jObject = new JSONObject(String to json);
            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
                JSONArray array = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("legs");
                for(int j=0; j<array.length(); j++){
                    String text = array.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("duration").getString("text");
                }
            }
```